# ¿Cómo puedo obtener todas las rutas dentro de un prefijo o grupo en lumen / laravel?

Tags: laravel, lumen

Estoy trabajando una `REST API` con `Lumen` y mi archivo `routes/web.php` es el siguiente:

```
$router->get('/', function () use ($router) {
    return $router->app->version();
});

$router->group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => ['CORS']], function () use ($router){

        $router->group(['middleware' => 'Files'], function () use ($router){
            $router->post('upload_file', 'ImporterController@uploadFile');
        });

        $router->get('version', function () {
            echo json_encode(['version' => 1]);
        });

        $router->get('methods', function () use ($router){
            return $router->getRoutes();
        });
});
```

Cuando entro por el navegador a la ruta `localhost/api/v1/methods` me devuelve un `JSON` con lo siguiente:

```
{
    "GET/": {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "/",
        "action": [
            {}
        ]
    },
    "POST/api/v1/upload_file": {
        "method": "POST",
        "uri": "/api/v1/upload_file",
        "action": {
            "uses": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\ImporterController@uploadFile",
            "middleware": [
                "CORS",
                "Files"
            ]
        }
    },
    "GET/api/v1/version": {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "/api/v1/version",
        "action": {
            "0": {},
            "middleware": [
                "CORS"
            ]
        }
    },
    "GET/api/v1/methods": {
        "method": "GET",
        "uri": "/api/v1/methods",
        "action": {
            "0": {},
            "middleware": [
                "CORS"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Como se puede ver en el anterior JSON me devuelve todas las rutas incluyendo la uri " **/** " yo quisiera que solo me devolviera lo que está dentro de el prefijo " **api/v1** " o dentro del mismo grupo, gracias